# Flume transferring gzip files

Tags: hdfs, hadoop-streaming, flume

I would like to transfer gzip file to hdfs. The option I am exploring is spooldir. I am having issue with specifying the remote location for the spooldir. Any suggestions please:

```
agent1.sources = src-1
agent1.channels = c1
agent1.sinks = k1

agent1.sources.src-1.type = spooldir
agent1.sources.src-1.channels = c1
agent1.sources.src-1.hostname = ipaddress
agent1.sources.src-1.spoolDir = /var/logs/webserver
agent1.channels.c1.type = memory

agent1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
agent1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
agent1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = hdfspath
agent1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = CompressedStream
agent1.sinks.k1.hdfs.round  = true
agent1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundValue = 10
agent1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundUnit = minute
```

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

The spooling directory source needs to point to a directory on the local system where flume is running.  This line is not a valid option for the spooling directory source:

```
agent1.sources.src-1.hostname = ipaddress
```